# System won't boot up properly - screens turning off and on. Only when second monitor is plugged in

Tags: gnome, graphics

So I have a very strange problem.

My Ubuntu system refuses to boot up. It shows the boot screen,  but after that,  the monitors go black and they are going off and on every time. Hitting ctrl alt f2 doesn't work. I think it's some graphical issue.

The login screen just doesn't come up. Both monitors go on and off and that's just going forever.

System specs:

i3 4130
8 GB of RAM
GTX 750 Ti
GA-H81M-HD3

***Update***

I̶ ̶c̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶c̶l̶u̶s̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶w̶r̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶N̶v̶i̶d̶i̶a̶ ̶d̶r̶i̶v̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶G̶T̶X̶ ̶c̶a̶r̶d̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶G̶P̶U̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶B̶I̶O̶S̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶u̶r̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶I̶n̶t̶e̶l̶ ̶H̶D̶ ̶o̶n̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶p̶l̶u̶g̶g̶e̶d̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶m̶o̶n̶i̶t̶o̶r̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶b̶o̶a̶r̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶P̶C̶ ̶b̶o̶o̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶s̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶n̶o̶w̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶i̶n̶s̶t̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶r̶i̶v̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶G̶T̶X̶ ̶c̶a̶r̶
d̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶I̶n̶t̶e̶l̶ ̶H̶D̶ ̶g̶r̶a̶p̶h̶i̶c̶s̶.̶

***Update 2***

Nvidia driver isnt the issue here. It has something to do with 2 monitors being plugged in. I booted the machine with only ONE monitor plugged in the GTX card and it booted up fine. But when I plug two monitors on the GTX card, Ubuntu will simply not boot up.

Comment: Clean you RAM and fix in next slot and try.

Comment: RAM is not the issue. I am dual booting Windows and it boots up fine.

Comment: Just a quick update: I fully diagnosed what could be the problem and came to the conclusion that there is something wrong with the Nvidia graphics drivers.  I fully disabled the GPU and turned on the Intel HD in the BIOS, following by that I plugged the monitor into the motherboard instead of the GPU and Ubuntu booted up without any problems. This is where I came to a conclusion that there is an issue with the Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please write an answer below instead of including it as part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved the issue and this topic can be closed. For anyone having a dual monitor issue. I would say, boot into Ubuntu with only ONE monitor connected. Then go to Nvidia Settings, go to ¨X server display information¨, then click: ¨Reset¨ and then hit apply. While the computer is running, connect the second display to your PC. One connected, click ¨Detect Displays¨. The second monitor should be on. Again, click on ¨Reset¨ and then reboot the machine. Issue solved =)