# Problem with Login-Screen with dual monitor mode since Ubuntu Unity/Gnome 16.04.02

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, login-screen, multiple-monitors

I'm working with an Lenovo T400 with onboard intel graphics combined with a Mini Dock for the last years. I use one DVI-Monitor and one VGA-Monitor/Display. Everything worked well until the ubdate from Ubuntu 16.04.1 ->16.04.2 (same in ubuntu gnome).

After updating I'm confronted with the following problem. 
All Displays do not work in the login window. The screen is black, you see loginscreen for a few sceonds and then the laptop switches automatically in power-safe mode. If you try to wake up also. 
If you boot with only one monitor (dvi or vga) everything works well. Also if you remove at the loginscreen one of both monitors, the loginscreen became visible. 
After loggin in, it is possible to connect a second monitor.

I would be happy if anyone of you is able to find a solution for my problem

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866087/system-wont-boot-up-properly-screens-turning-off-and-on-only-when-second-mon?noredirect=1#comment1339190_866087

Comment: this solution works but it is quiete uncomfortable.. do anyone have an idea?